# Does the game end if all current investigators are defeated?

Tags: eldritch-horror

Page 11 of the rulebook says the game ends if all investigators are **eliminated** from the game. Does this mean that if all currently active investigators die, the game ends, or does it mean if the pool of investigators from which we draw new ones gets exhausted as well, then it ends. We had a case where all 4 of our investigators simultaneously lost all sanity, and I wasn't sure whether to fast forward to the end of the mythos and redraw 4 investigators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/e3/a5/e3a58886-072b-4ca2-9709-e723af370203/eh_errata__faq_2016-01-19.pdf) (Page 3)

> Q. If all investigators are defeated at the same time, do investigators lose the game?
>
> A No. At the end of the Mythos Phase, each defeated investigator will choose a new investigator to play as. However, if being defeated would cause a player to be eliminated, such as if the Ancient One has awoken, all players could be eliminated. In this case, investigators lose the game.

As for when players are eliminated when defeated, the [Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/39/c1/39c182c1-6b0d-46c4-b5eb-dd6886b4c798/eh01_reference_guide1.pdf) (Page 5) provides:

> - Eliminated players do not choose new investigators after being 
>     defeated.
> - If an investigator is defeated and there are no undefeated 
>     investigators available, that player is eliminated.
> - If an investigator is defeated or devoured after the Ancient One 
>     awakens, that player is eliminated.
> - If the investigators win the game, any eliminated players win as 
>     well.
> - If all players have been eliminated, the investigators lose the game.